# Mocking Symfony services in Codeception unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, symfony, mocking, codeception

I'm trying to mock some Symfony services that make HTTP requests, etc. to purify my unit tests in Codeception. I can create the mocks, but I can't insert them into Symfony's/Codeception's test container for dependency injection because it says the service is already  initialised. Looking at the source code, it's simply that it already exists with that name. (`$container->set(MyService::class, $mock_service);`) If I test the mocks in isolation, they work as expected, but so far I haven't found a way to get Symfony to use dependency injection to override the normal services when testing dependent classes.

Once a mock service has been created with Codeception, how do you get Symfony to use the mock in dependency injection?

Comment: Please try the following: https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/service_container.html#remove-services. How do you create the service that is in $mock_service?